# Django admin for a changing sub-category field

Tags: django

I have a model named Category and I have another model named SubCategory, which uses a foreign key to the Category model.

Now I wish to have an Item Model, which on the admin site will have a Category item and a SubCategory item. But I wish that when choosing Category, the SubCategory will only show the SubCategory relates to the specific Category.

I assume I'll only need a foreign key to the SubCategory in the Item model because every SubCategory can have only one Category.

Could this be accomplished on the admin site?

Comment: I really think you shouldn't have a subcategory model unless you have very good reason to. You can relate a category to itself by using a string https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: @Hedde can you expound on your reason for warning against a subcategory model?

Comment: @andersra it's not a warning, it's a matter of simplicity. Unless you have completely different category entities, why would you create two classes that are in essence, the same? Creating an optional parent_id field should work fine in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Example of solution

```
models.py

class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True, db_index=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created_at', )
    verbose_name = 'category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

class SubCategory(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='souscatégories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True, db_index=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created_at', )
    verbose_name = 'sub-category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'sub-categories'

class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='produits', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, related_name='produits', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True, null=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  class Meta:
    ordering = ["-created_at", "-updated_at"]
```

Then add route with JSON response

```
views.py

import json
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import SubCategory, Category


def get_subcategory(request):
  id = request.GET.get('id', '')
  result = list(SubCategory.objects.filter(
  category_id=int(id)).values('id', 'name'))
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")

urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name = 'product'
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^/getSubcategory/$', views.get_subcategory)
]
```

Now you have to override change_form.html of Django admin for your product app to add some JavaScript code to do the magic.

The location of this file is not important. You can put it inside your app and it will still work.

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %} {% load static %} {% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
// inspect html to check id of category select dropdown.
$(document).on("change", "select#id_category", function () {
$.getJSON("/getSubcategory/", { id: $(this).val() }, function (j) {
var options = '<option value="">---------</option>';
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
options +=
'<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + "</option>";
}
// inspect html to check id of subcategory select dropdown.
$("select#id_subcategory").html(options);
});
});
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks https://medium.com/@malak.br for this solution.
More details https://betterprogramming.pub/optimizing-django-admin-6a1187ddbb09